# UITableview buttons getting highlighted on scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have toggle buttons in my tableview cells and I click them on for some cells but when I scroll down, those same buttons are selected for the bottom cells as well even though I didn't select them yet. I know this is happening because of the tableview reusing cells...is there any way I can fix this?

The cells are dynamic, not static.

what the tableview looks like

[image]

** EDIT: Also, lemme know if my logic seems alright: I tried creating a mutable array in my viewcontroller class and then setting all it's values to @"0". Then, in my tableviewcell's class, I set the value in the array to @"1" at the index of the current cell if I select the button, so then back in my viewcontroller class, I can tell if I have already selected a button at that cell or not. The only flaw is that I can't access the array in my tableviewcell's class, it is coming out at null...i guess that it because of the mvc pattern in objective c. Any advice?

**EDIT**

I am still unable to resolve my issue. Can someone please help me? I have been stuck on it for a while now!

I am trying to create a tableview where the cells have a check and cross button and when I click the check button, it should turn green, but the same button in other cells should remain gray, however, when I scroll down, some cells that I didn't select buttons in still turn green...because of cell recycling.

I am using delegates and protocols right now but it isn't working; perhaps I am using it wrong?

I am setting yesChecked value in IBaction functions in my cell class, and in my viewcontroller class, I am using that yesChecked value to see what color to give to the button based on whether it says "yes" or "no".

Kindly help! Thanks!

```
@protocol DetailsTableViewCellDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) customCell:(DetailsTableViewCell *)cell yesBtnPressed:(bool)yes;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * yesChecked;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to select or deselect them in `cellForRowAt`. For example if your cell had a `leftButton` property and you had a model like this, you could do something like the following:

```
@interface Model : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL selected;

@end
```

```
@protocol CustomCellDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)cellActionTapped:(UITableViewCell *)cell;

@end
```

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL leftButtonSelected;
@property (weak, nonatomic, nullable) id<CustomCellDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

```
// ModelViewController.h
@interface ModelViewController : UIViewController<CustomCellDelegate>

@end
```

```
// ModelViewController.m
@interface ViewController () {
    NSArray<Model*>* models;
}

@end
```

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"reuseIdentifier"];
    ((CustomCell *)cell).delegate = self;
    ((CustomCell *)cell).leftButtonSelected = models[indexPath.row].selected;
    return cell;
}

- (void)cellActionTapped:(UITableViewCell *)cell {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    // Update data source using (maybe) indexPath.row
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but I'm using objective-c

Comment: Also, lemme know if my logic seems alright: I tried creating a mutable array in my viewcontroller class and then setting all it's values to @"0". Then, in my tableviewcell's class, I set the value in the array to @"1" at the index of the current cell if I select the button, so then back in my viewcontroller class, I can tell if I have already selected a button at that cell or not. The only flaw is that I can't access the array in my tableviewcell's class, it is coming out at null...i guess that it because of the mvc pattern in objective c. Any advice?

Comment: It's basically the same in Obj-C but I've updated my answer. You should implement a delegate in your cells so that the tap within your cell updates the data source in the ViewController. Having a data source at the cell level isn't going to work given the reusable nature of cells.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! I'm sorry to bother you again, I am having trouble figuring out delegate for the cell, can you provide me with some sample code or send a helpful link?

Comment: I updated the answer to include an example of a delegate. You will have to change the parameters and logic based on what you want to achieve but I think it will give you a general idea of the approach.