# Delegates and Protocols for UIButton toggle in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, delegates, swift-protocols

I posted this one before: [UITableview buttons getting highlighted on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63750479/uitableview-buttons-getting-highlighted-on-scroll)

but I am unable to resolve my issue. Can someone please help me? I have been stuck on it for a while now!

I am trying to create a tableview where the cells have a check and cross button and when I click the check button, it should turn green, but the same button in other cells should remain gray, however, when I scroll down, some cells that I didn't select buttons in still turn green...because of cell recycling.

I am using delegates and protocols right now but it isn't working; perhaps I am using it wrong?

I am setting yesChecked value in IBaction functions in my cell class, and in my viewcontroller class, I am using that yesChecked value to see what color to give to the button based on whether it says "yes" or "no".

Kindly help! Thanks!

```
    @protocol DetailsTableViewCellDelegate <NSObject>
    
    - (void) customCell:(DetailsTableViewCell *)cell yesBtnPressed:(bool)yes;
    
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * yesChecked;
```

Comment: Don't post multiple question, the answer in the previous post should obviously fixed the issue. Add the `BOOL` property on your model class and enable the checker in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and it will appear correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UITableview buttons getting highlighted on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63750479/uitableview-buttons-getting-highlighted-on-scroll)

Comment: If you want to add more information about what you've tried, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63750576/edit) your original question instead of posting a duplicate, thanks!